# Absolute links to foreign site using routerLink

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I wrote the component, which simulate dynamic menu to navigate my application.
Application load (from API) available menu position and shows them for user and overlight active position (adding class "active"). I implemented this feature in this way:

**menu.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'menu',
    templateUrl: 'menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

    menuItems: Position[];

    ngOnInit() {
       //some code... (loading menu positions)
    }
}
```

**menu.component.html**

```
<a class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let item of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="[item.actionURL]">
  <i class="fa {{item?.icon}}"></i>
  <span>{{item?.label}}</span>
</a>
```

**position.ts**

```
export class Position {

    label: string;
    actionURL: string;
    icon: string;

    constructor(label: string, actionURL: string, icon: string) {
        this.label = label;
        this.actionURL = actionURL;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, until I use relative paths in actionURL attribute. **What have to I do, to using relative and absolute paths in menu?** I have to keep overlight active buttons, but I would like to redirect to foreign website by my menu component.

Comment: You can't navigate outside of your Angular application using `routerLink`. You a normal `<a href="...">` instead.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ok, but how can i detect absolute or relative path? Have you any idea? How can I block routerLink for absolute path and set href attribute? Or maybe are you trying tell, that mixed realtive and aboslute links is impossible

Comment: How do your links look like? I can't tell how you can differentiate them. Perhaps when they start with `http:/` or `https:/`.

Comment: yes, they start with http://. but I'm not sure, that checking if string contains characters string is a good practise, is it?

Comment: I don't see another way.